# Is there a Ruby built-in class or module (other than String) that has method #to_str?

Tags: ruby

For some testing, I'm looking for a Ruby built-in class or module (other than String) that has method #to_str.

(I know that many have method #to_s, but that's not what I'm looking for.)

I've pored over the docs, and can't find any such.

Comment: Look at the right column on this page: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/
There is just String#to_str. You can always define your to_str method for a certain Class. But what's the goal?

Comment: The Ruby programming language supports inspection/reflection (e.g. `ObjectSpace`) which you can make use of to find the answer by yourself. It's also more trustworthy than any kind of documentation and even may raise new questions.

Comment: Thanks, @iGian.  True, nothing in core, but still could be in std-lib.

Env.store(name, value) coerces both name and value via #to_str, so was looking for a non-String method to illustrate.

ENV's own tests cheat thus:

  it "coerces the key argument with #to_str" do
    k = mock("key")
    k.should_receive(:to_str).and_return("foo")
    ENV.send(@method, k, "bar")
    ENV["foo"].should == "bar"
  end

Comment: @BurdetteLamar you can wrap code in bactics in comments like `puts 'hello'` for example. For more tips click the little `help` link below the `Add Comment` button when typing comments.

Comment: Thanks, @lacostenycoder, good info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is to ask Ruby herself:

```
ObjectSpace.
  each_object(Module).
  select {|mod| mod.instance_methods(false).include?(:to_str) } - 
    [String]
#=> [NameError::message]
```

So, it turns out the only other class that defines `to_str` is an internal implementation class inside `NameError`. Which makes sense, really, there are not that many objects in Ruby that *are* strings but are not instances of `String`.

I would expect a Ropes library (if such a thing exists) to implement `to_str`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer the question if there is any class that implements the `#to_str` method. Rather this answer focuses on:

> For some testing, I'm looking for a Ruby built-in class or module (other than String) that has method #to_str.

You could create an temporary class for testing purposes that forwards all calls to the internal string.

```
require 'delegate'

# create an anonymous class inheriting from DelegateClass(String)
my_string_class = Class.new(DelegateClass(String))
my_string       = my_string_class.new("Hello World!")

my_string.is_a?(String)     #=> false
"Hello World!" == my_string #=> true
```

The reason the above comparison returns `true` can be found in the *String* [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/String.html#method-i-3D-3D).

> ### str == obj → true or false
>
> Equality—Returns whether `str == obj`, similar to `Object#==`.
>
> If `obj` is not an instance of [String](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/String.html) but responds to `to_str`, then the two strings are compared using `obj.==`.
>
> Otherwise, returns similarly to [`#eql?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/String.html#method-i-eql-3F), comparing length and content.

You could also skip the creation of the anonymous class and use *SimpleDelegator* instead.

```
my_string = SimpleDelegator.new("Hello World!")
```

For more info about delegators take a look at the [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.4/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/index.html).